# query parameterization to avoid SQL injection

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I am new to this, can anyone help me please?

it was said to me that SQL injection exploit can read sensitive data from the database with this way of coding. and I need to parameterize the SQL queries so that the application is not vulnerable to SQL Injection. can someone help me with that?

```
if(isset($_GET['n']))
      {
      $id=$_GET['n'];
 $query= mysql_query("select * from announcements where announce_id=" . $id);
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

this should do this for example:
announcement.php?ann=223

thank you very much

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I would advise you to switch to a different database driver for starters. take a look at MySQLi or PDO.